# Using a dynamic LIMIT in a SQL Query Redshift

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, limit, amazon-redshift, netezza

I have a Redshift and Netezza query where the `COUNT(*)` grows whenever I run it, as most tables append rows with more sales, etc. Anyway, I'm looking for the top 20% by price, so I'm using `ORDER BY price`, then changing the limit by doing the mental math to get the top 20%, i.e. if `COUNT(*)=10,000`, then I'll add a static `LIMIT 2000`. Tomorrow, maybe it'll be 12,000 rows though, then I'll need to run the `COUNT(*)` and  change the `LIMIT 2400` again. This is obviously not scalable.

I'm trying to edit the query to include a dynamic limit, looking for the top 20% and easily changing between the percentages: 5%, 10%, etc. So no matter the count of rows, I get consistent results.

Example query below:

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM orders
WHERE
 sale_date >= '2018-01-01'
ORDER BY 
 price DESC
LIMIT 2000
```

I'd like to have something that's more like:

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM orders
WHERE
 sale_date >= '2018-01-01'
ORDER BY 
 price DESC
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) * 0.2 FROM orders)
```

Not sure if Redshift/Netezza supports this functionality. I've seen ONE StackOverflow question where it was possible in MySQL using a variable function, but I'm working in Redshift and Netezza. Anyone have any ideas for how to create this? Thank you!

Comment: I would first check your initial approach. It may work without any workarounds [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3c5a3c373f24c197552c0da44a40c383)

Comment: @lad2025 the initial works fine on a static table where I know the exact count of total rows, but as the table continues to grow, I have to continually find the total count, then adjust the LIMIT which I don't want to do, hence this StackOverflow question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is `row_number()` and `count(*)`:

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY price DESC) as seqnum,
             COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
      FROM orders o
      WHERE sale_date >= '2018-01-01'
     ) o
WHERE seqnum <= cnt * 0.2
ORDER BY price DESC;
```

You don't have to use two functions.  One will do.  For instance:

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY price DESC) p
      FROM orders o
      WHERE sale_date >= '2018-01-01'
     ) o
WHERE p <= 0.2
ORDER BY price DESC;
```