Explode values in dbt
I'm trying to replicate the repeat_by and explode functions from Polars using dbt with a Redshift database but am having difficulty finding an equivalent solution.
Here's the sample Polars DataFrame code for context:
NOTE: I don't need replicate column, if that's an issue, then don't worry about it
import polars as pl

# Sample DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
    "age": [25, 30, 35],
    "city": ["New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago"],
    "replicate": [2, 3, 1]
})

Polars DataFrame output:
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────────┬─────┬─────────────┬───────────┐
│ name    ┆ age ┆ city        ┆ replicate │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---       │
│ str     ┆ i64 ┆ str         ┆ i64       │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════════════╪═══════════╡
│ Alice   ┆ 25  ┆ New York    ┆ 2         │
│ Bob     ┆ 30  ┆ Los Angeles ┆ 3         │
│ Charlie ┆ 35  ┆ Chicago     ┆ 1         │
└─────────┴─────┴─────────────┴───────────┘

Using the repeat_by and explode functions:
df.select(pl.all().repeat_by('replicate').explode())

Result:
shape: (6, 4)
┌─────────┬─────┬─────────────┬───────────┐
│ name    ┆ age ┆ city        ┆ replicate │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---       │
│ str     ┆ i64 ┆ str         ┆ i64       │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════════════╪═══════════╡
│ Alice   ┆ 25  ┆ New York    ┆ 2         │
│ Alice   ┆ 25  ┆ New York    ┆ 2         │
│ Bob     ┆ 30  ┆ Los Angeles ┆ 3         │
│ Bob     ┆ 30  ┆ Los Angeles ┆ 3         │
│ Bob     ┆ 30  ┆ Los Angeles ┆ 3         │
│ Charlie ┆ 35  ┆ Chicago     ┆ 1         │
└─────────┴─────┴─────────────┴───────────┘

I need help finding a way to achieve the same result in dbt with Redshift.

I used JOIN and a CROSS JOIN since you mentioned generate_series is not supported.
I tested this in Snowflake , since I dont have redshift.
I guess the syntax might not be the exact same, but still should work.
let me know if it works for you.
SET tbl_count = (SELECT max(replicate) FROM my_table);

WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT 
        row_number() OVER ( order by 1) AS num
    FROM 
        (SELECT 1 FROM my_table LIMIT $tbl_count ) )
        ,
repeated_data AS (
    SELECT 
        t.name,
        t.age,
        t.city,
        t.replicate
    FROM 
        my_table t
    CROSS JOIN numbers
    WHERE numbers.num <= t.replicate
)
SELECT 
    name, 
    age, 
    city,
    replicate

FROM 
    repeated_data
ORDER BY name, age;

Trying with Recursion since using Limit variable is tricky in Redshift
WITH RECURSIVE numbers AS (
    -- Base case: start from 1
    SELECT 1 AS num
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive case: increment the number by 1 each time
    SELECT num + 1
    FROM numbers
    WHERE num < (SELECT max(replicate) FROM my_table) -- Stop when num reaches max(replicate)
),
repeated_data AS (
    SELECT 
        t.name,
        t.age,
        t.city,
        t.replicate
    FROM 
        my_table t
    CROSS JOIN numbers
    WHERE numbers.num <= t.replicate
)
SELECT 
    name, 
    age, 
    city,
    replicate
FROM 
    repeated_data
ORDER BY 
    name, age;

Output :


hey, thanks for the reply, unfortunately does not work with redshift, when attempting to set query as limit it gives me an error that I cannot set limit as subquery.

Limit variable can be used in redshift, see a similar example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687149/using-a-dynamic-limit-in-a-sql-query-redshift.
I have edited the answer with a different approach using recursion, let me know

Hey, thank you for the reply, though the answer was correct there was a decision to just stick with python and shrink the data. Though thanks and hopefully this reply will be useful for someone down the line

Glad it worked in a different way for you :) and thanks a lot for your kind words! yes definitely would be useful for someone in similar situation :)
